# How to do slide show for content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want content slider with fade effect.

I got good script form http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/.

But it only works fine with image.

How to do it with content?

Answer (score 1):

check this plug in : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

[13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)